# What does !escape do in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

What does !escape do in the following line of VBA code? There isn't a escape() anywhere and I searched on google for a in build escape function but seem that doesn't exist.

```
  Application.OnKey "%{F11}", "1006.xls!escape"
```

**[EDITED / ANSWER]**
Later I found it was **Laroux Virus** that corrupt excel files. The infected excel file will try to call a non-existing macro named **"escape"** from 1006.xls intentionally to annoy the user with a harmless pop-up exception every time the infected excel file is open.

Comment: Its probably an attempt to reassign the `Alt-F11` key to prevent the VBA IDE opening.  The fact `escape` doesn't exist won't prevent the `.OnKey` action being called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What this code does is call the macro "escape" in workbook 1006.xls

When you Press Alt F11, the code will run the macro "Escape". This method is usually used when you want to call a macro from another workbook.

HTH

Sid

Comment: I'm viewing the VBA code but cannot find a function name "escape". Is that a default command?

Comment: Open the 1006.xls. The macro should be there in one of the modules.

Comment: If the macro is not there then that code will not do anything :) I would like to see the 1006.xls. Would it possible for you to upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here. I would like to examine the file myself :)

Comment: 1006.xls is actually a virus file infected my friend's computer. While I can clear it I'm also curious how this piece work. I don't think I will upload a virus, you can search for "1006(潘).xls" to get the complete source code, which consist of three functions only.

Comment: That is the reason why I asked you to upload it in wikisend.com. ;) I could have opened the file with macros disabled and explained how that works :). All I can say at the moment is that when you press Alt + F11 the "Escape" macro runs. Without seeing the code, I can't say what "Escape" does.

Comment: the antivirus software Avira cleared the files. But you're right, the fact that the escape code is missing was a reason why 1006.xls poped up with an exception when the other infected excels trying to call the macro.

Answer (score 0):

On press of `F11`, sub process `escape` will be called which is lying on `1006.xls`

I have come across, something similar what you are trying:-

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fclub.excelhome.net%2Fthread-816230-1-1.html

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.officefans.net%2Fcdb%2Fviewthread.php%3Faction%3Dprintable%26tid%3D164129